# SVG: Reuse existing gradient definition, but rotate/flip it

Tags: svg, gradient

I've searched but can't find an answer to this one. Suppose I have a gradient defined in an SVG, for example:

```
<linearGradient id="myCustomGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="80%" style="stop-color: #4D4D94;" />
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: #FFFFFF;" />
</linearGradient>
```

I can use that in a shape by doing something like:

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" style="fill: url(#myCustomGradient)" />
```

...this will create a rectangle with a nice gradient going from blue at the top to white at the bottom.

Now, suppose I'd like to produce a shape with the same gradient *but in the opposite direction* (i.e. going from blue at the *bottom* to white at the top). **Is it possible to reuse the existing gradient definition but to transform (i.e. flip) it somehow?**

I know about the `gradientTransform` attribute, but this only seems to apply when defining a new gradient.

Answer (score 10):

Sure, you create another gradient and give it and xlink:href to your first gradient. E.g.

```
<linearGradient id="myCustomRotatedGradient" xlink:href="#myCustomGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(180, 150, 25)"/>
```

Any attributes you don't set use the ones in the referenced gradient. If you don't set any stops then the referenced gradient stops are used too.

If you want to flip it, gradientTransform of scale(-1) may work better.

Comment: So you really have to create a new gradient definition for each shape that wants to use it? This seems inefficient. But then maybe the `xlink:href` protocol allows for reuse under the hood? Imagine a page with 1000 elements distributed across the viewport, each with a gradient. The only difference between the gradient in each is the x,y offset of the gradient's coordinate system; instantiating a new gradient for each seems way overkill.

Comment: Yeah, so, I read up on `xlink:href` and all the attributes and child elements (e.g. `<stop>`s) are inherited, as described in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink%3Ahref), under "Gradient elements". Just like you said. I found that `<use>` didn't work in this case, it had to be a `<linearGradient>` with an `xlink:href`. I guess this leverages SVG's intrinsic reusability, and while it requires a new element, it's still efficient.